# Progress Bar is not shown from one to other form load

Tags: c#

I have a Main Form and a Progress bar on other form, On load on Main form i want to load progress bar
on other form say Comscanner, i have written two methods in Comscanner form below:

```
    public void SetMaximum(int max)
    {
        PrgComPortScan.Maximum = max;
        PrgComPortScan.Value   = 0;
    }

    public void Increment()
    {
        if(PrgComPortScan.Maximum > (PrgComPortScan.Value + 1)) 
        {
            PrgComPortScan.Value = PrgComPortScan.Value + 1;
        }  
    }
```

but while calling these methods on my main form with timer i am not able to show progressbar 
I also used timer control and its tick property am i missing something?

Comment: Your Increment() can simply call PerformStep().

Answer (score 0):

For access progressbar form one from to another try below code :

```
frmProgramExport objexport = new frmProgramExport(); // Where frmProgramExport your from name 
objexport.prgImport.PerformStep();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want two forms to update at the same time on the `OnLoad` event. 
[image: ScrShot]

Here is the code for the 2nd form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Application.DoEvents();            
    }

    public void SetProgress(int value)
    {
        progressBar1.Value=value;
    }
    public void SetProgress(int value, int max)
    {
        progressBar1.Maximum=max;
        progressBar1.Value=value;            
    }
    public void Increment()
    {
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    }
}
```

and here is the code for the main form:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        this.Show();
        label1.Text="Initializing Form1";
        Form1 dlg=new Form1();
        dlg.Show();
        Application.DoEvents();
        dlg.Location=new Point(this.Location.X+this.Size.Width+5, this.Location.Y);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1400);

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            label1.Text="Setting Progress Bar at "+(i+1).ToString()+" of 10";
            dlg.SetProgress(i+1, 10);
            Application.DoEvents();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1400);
        }
        label1.Text="Done!";
    }
}
```

and it all starts with

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
```